# How to build a centered menu with fixed width and 100% sides

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to build a menu like this:

[image]

The menu is centered and got a specific with (e.g. 800px). The other two divs should be aligned to right and left side of the browser.

Is this possible with pure css?

Comment: Yes it is possible with pure css

Comment: @Huangism you need more likes :-)

Comment: I give what the people ask for :)

Comment: What all have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**EDIT :**

As Chad commented, tables are made for tabular data as this is not tabluar data, here is a solution without tables :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Thfdy/13/)**

It uses divs with `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;`

---

It is possible with pure CSS using tables :

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Thfdy/4/)**

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="left">
            ALIGN LEFT
        </td>
        <td id="center">
            MENU
        </td>
        <td id="right">
            ALIGN RIGHT
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
 html,body{
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    table{
        width:100%;
    }
    td {
        border:1px solid red;
        height:100px;
    }
    #center{
        width:800px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #right{
        text-align:right;
    }
```

Comment: Noo :( tables are for tabular data

Comment: @Chad That is very true ;) I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: A little better ;) why not just use `width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;`?

Comment: @Chad because of the red border around the left and right divs.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;`?

Comment: @Chad no, there would be no possibility to get that red border around left and right divs with `box-sizing` see here http://jsfiddle.net/Thfdy/12/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50140/discussion-between-web-tiki-and-chad)

Comment: I guess I didn't realize he wanted 3 columns-- thought he just wanted the one. My only other thought is to do absolute positioning for those, which is not a good option. `display: table;` should work fine.